# Cannot correctly format a java.sql.Timestamp(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S) to string

Tags: java, string, timestamp

I try to format

```
date = 2015-05-07 10:12:14.000243
```

to 
equivalent string this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(date);
```

But I getting wrong value:

```
2015-05-07 10:12:14.0
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: How is it wrong? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Like my date (2015-05-07 10:12:14.000243)

Comment: You mean you want the last digits from miliseconds (000243)? Otherwise it looks the same

Comment: Yes, last digits 000243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to obtain the exact date you need the apropriate number of milisecond digits (you just used 1 - S).

With 6 digits for miliseconds:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").format(date);
```

For a new date, the output will be:

```
2015-05-18 12:17:56.000501
```

Read more on [SimpleDateFormat's Date and Time pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

---

Update to comment:

If your date indeed does come the way described, the answer i provided should work. As Jesper mentioned in the comment

> Beware that not all databases store dates with millisecond precision

Below i created a new Date object with the exact date you provided.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2015-05-07 10:12:14.000243");
```

When you print out the value, you will get it the way you want it:

```
sdf.format(date1);
```

Comment: Yes. I try to add execute this code, but my output is: 2015-05-07 10:12:14.000000

Comment: I updated the answer . If you get that output, you have a bad input date

Comment: @ValentinBlokhin Beware that not all databases store dates with millisecond precision. Maybe you're using a column type that only has seconds precision, so that the milliseconds will be 0.

Comment: You're right. This was db issue. I have bad timestamp in my db. Thanks all.